# Data upload command not working for google app engine datastore (local version)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is the command that I am using. I have followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata. When I use the same command for the same application that I have hosted on the web, the command works and I can see the data in the datastore. But the same command is not working for my local copy of the application. The error I am getting is:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>   [ERROR   ] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).

But I am not really using any credentials to host it locally. Please help.

```
./appcfg.py upload_data --application=say_hello --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=output.csv --kind=Dashboard --url=http:hostname:8080/_ah/remote_api
```

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters are right but the authentication is failing, pass in the -oauth2 flag:

appcfg.py --oauth2 update app.yaml

Then the rest of your appcfg.py  should authenticate.  If it still doesn't work your appid or url is probably off.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mac, you should have administration privileges on your mac. if not, put sudo on the beginning of the command

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why that error gets raised unfortunately, all I know is that it can be solved by passing the `--email` flag. Simple run this and when it asks for a password, hit `Enter`.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=output.csv --application=[your-app-id] --email=test@example.com path/to/folder/containing/app/yaml/
```

Where [your-app-id] seems to be in the format `dev~[application-name]`. e.g `dev~something-engine-v2`.

NB: Also **ensure HTTP**, as I also got the same error when accidentally accessing localhost with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, and it turned out to be that I had a wildcard rule that was getting in the way of the remote_api url.

Below is an excerpt of my app.yaml. (I was archiving a legacy app, so I didn't care that no one could access the site now.)

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on

handlers:

# - url: /.*
#   script: main.py
```